# Foreman + unicorn - heavy cpu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, sinatra, unicorn, foreman

I have a ruby 2.0 sinatra 'faceless' app that serves up json by calling an external service. It works fine.

The main app is run on port 80 in a ubuntu machine.

I also start an instance using 'foreman start' - so it runs on port 5000 on the same ubuntu virtual machine.

On the port 80 instance, the process 'foreman master' soaks up CPU time, while with the same load, the one on port 5000 uses essentially 0 CPU.

```
 $ ps -a l
 F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND

 4     0  1615  1614  20   0  26140 17236 wait   Sl+  tty1       0:28 foreman: master 

 0  1000  1899  1659  20   0  25036 16612 wait   Sl+  pts/1      0:00 foreman: master
```

The apps were started at the same time and both had the same load (very light for 20 mins).

The only difference I can see is that the problem one is started on port 80 using a sudo command, and the other one is just started as a user process.

Is there a difference in how foreman needs to output log entries in a tty terminal vs a pts/1 terminal?

Note that with 40 people banging away on the app, the foreman master process is using 90% cpu while all the other ruby processes that are supposed to be doing the work are at 1% (9 unicorns).

I think its something to do with terminal output handled differently but I'm not sure.

Thanks for any help.

Is there a way to tell foreman or ruby to not write log stuff out at all?

EDIT
I now think that it is related to terminal logging, since i turned 95% of it off for the deployment app, and loads are better, but still higher than the normal non rvmsudo command.